# how to disable ios simulator keyboard in "xcode 12"?

Tags: xcode, react-native, appium, webdriver-io

**"help"**
I am doing automated testing using "appium" and "ios" keyboard is making issue in text-input, so i want to disable the keyboard from popping up.

**I tried following options**>>

i/o > Keyboard > connect hardware keyboard

I am selecting that connect hardware keyboard option but it will again rechecked when, I run test cases.  I also tried restart after selecting that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
`driver.hideDeviceKeyboard();`

See [docs](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/hide-keyboard/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to hide ios keyboard. A few listed below

1. send return key

```
IOSDriver< WebElement> AD= (IOSDriver) driver;
AD.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

2. send key code

```
driver.getKeyboard().pressKey("\n");
```